# Convert elasticsearch DSL query with multiple conditions to URI Search

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run the below Elasticsearch DSL query on Kibana Dev console it returns the result properly and I was trying to run the same through URI based query as HTTP URL its not working. I have tried search on doc and good, not getting the exact way to frame this query as HTTP based GET url.

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 100,
  "_source": [
    "fieldname1",
    "fieldname2"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "fieldname2"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "fieldname2": "*IGNORE*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any hints please.

Comment: Do you want to convert this query into URI based search ?

Comment: @TechnocratSid Yes. I want to convert this GET request to URI based search. like http://server.com/_search.......

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above query in [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request) format can be written as:

```
GET /_search?q=_exists_:fieldname2 AND !fieldname2:"*IGNORE*"&_source=fieldname1,fieldname2&size=100
```

The parameter **q** in URI maps to [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) query.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! I have searched a lot but somehow I didn't get this doc link.